# Account search app on visualforce apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

I creating visualforce app using apex, the problem is I stuck in not displaying the
Accounts. Can anyone help me with this? Here's my work so far;

[image: image so far]

my code;

```
<apex:page controller="AccountSearchController" sidebar="false" showHeader="true" tabStyle="account_search__tab">
<apex:form >
<apex:image value="https://c.na85.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0151U000000Beqt"/>
<apex:pageBlock title="Search Criteria" mode="edit" id="criteria">
     <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4">
         <apex:outputLabel value="Account Name"><br/>
             <apex:inputText value="{!acc.name}"/>
         </apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:outputLabel value="Country"><br/>
            <apex:inputText value="{!acc.billingcountry}"/>
        </apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:outputLabel value="Contact Name"><br/>
        <apex:inputText value="{!acc.owner}"/>
        </apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:outputLabel value="Account Type"><br/>
            <apex:selectList value="{!acc.Type}" style="width:173px " multiselect="false">
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:outputLabel>
     </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:commandButton value="Find Accounts" action="{!SearchAccountRec}"/>        
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!If(lstAccount.size>0,true,false)}" title="Search Result">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstAccount}" var="acc">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputLink value="/{!acc.id}">{!acc.Name}</apex:outputLink>                            
            </apex:column>                     
        </apex:pageBlockTable>           
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!If(lstAccount.size==0 && isResultDisplay == true,true,false)}" title="Search Result">            
            <apex:outputLabel value="No Result Found"></apex:outputLabel>           
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

```
public with sharing class AccountSearchController {

 public Account acc{ get; set; }
 public string strAccSearchString {get; set;}
 public List<Account> lstAccount {get; set;}
 public boolean isResultDisplay {get; set;}

 //  constructor
 public AccountSearchController(){
    lstAccount = new List<Account>();
    isResultDisplay = false;
  }  
 //  Search Function
 public void SearchAccountRec(){
    isResultDisplay = true;
    string strLikeString = '%'+strAccSearchString+'%';
    string strSOQL = 'select id,Name from Account where name LIKE: strLikeString order by Name asc';
    lstAccount = database.query(strSOQL);
}
}
```

I much appreciated if someone help me in other function/method like how to display the contact name of the account.

Answer (score 1):

in your soql query `select id,Name from Account where name LIKE :strLikeString order by Name asc` you are using `strLikeString` varibale. This variable is populating as `string strLikeString = '%'+strAccSearchString+'%';`. But look at `strAccSearchString` variable. It is not referecing on VF at all and is n't populating with anything. It is just `null`.  You want to have `acc.name` instead of `strAccSearchString` `string strLikeString = '%'+acc.Name+'%';`

---

field acc.Name is referencing in search criteria, but field `acc` isn't instantiated. You want to do it in controller constructor.  `acc = new Account();`

---

why do you use [dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) ? Always to use static soql if possible is a best practice. some errors could be observed during compilation in static soql (vs execution in dynamic soql)

---

summarizing all above, in order to have working example of your page,  you want to have the following controller:

```
public with sharing class AccountSearchController {
    public Account acc{ get; set; }
    public String strAccSearchString {get; set;}
    public List<Account> lstAccount {get; set;}
    public Boolean isResultDisplay {get; set;}

 //  constructor
    public AccountSearchController(){
        lstAccount = new List<Account>();
        isResultDisplay = false;
        acc = new Account();
    }
 //  Search Function
    public void SearchAccountRec(){
        isResultDisplay = true;
        String strLikeString = '%'+acc.Name+'%';
        lstAccount = [select id, Name from Account where name LIKE :strLikeString order by Name asc];
    }
}
```